# How to prevent line break before and after <script> tag (JavaScript) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a website written in HTML (and CSS of course)
I have one JavaScript in it... just a little slideshow.

There's an anchor tag with an image in it before the script
and after the script there's also a anchor tag with an image in it.

```
...
<a href="... .html">
    <img class="img" src="... .png" title="..."></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- the script text -->
</script>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="... .html">
    <img class="img" src="... .png" title="..."></a>
...
```

My problem is the line break before and after the script tag. I want it to be

> *image*    *slideshow(script)*    *image*

All used images (including the slideshow content) have the same height.

I've tried `display: inline;` and `white-space: nowrap;` (and every other white-space thing)
I've put it both directly into the  in the html file (`style="display:inline;"` or `style="white-space:nowrap;"` and into the css file (`script { display: inline; }` and `script { white-space: nowrap; }`)

Does anybody know how to prevent the line breaks before and after the script tag??

Comment: The script tag should not be in your HTML body to begin with.

Comment: You could try `script{display:none}` but that should be the default anyways.

Comment: also note that `&nbsp;` is not a good substitute for real margins.

Comment: Any chance you could have accidentally set `display:block` to one of the `a`'s or `img`s?

Comment: It not the script tag causing the line break, it's the script.  If you replace your script with something like 'var x = 0;' you'll see there is no break. But also what Diodeus said.

Comment: @Diodeus I personally prefer my scripts in the head, however, there is absolutely nothing wrong with [putting scripts](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) [in the body](http://stackoverflow.com/a/436425/1090190).

Comment: @JanDvorak &nbsp; thing: I know :DD, but I've already used the margin for something else (I'm beginner and it works, I'm happy though :D)

Comment: @JanDvorak before I added the script there was a normal image instead of a slideshow, and without the script / slideshow it worked fine (without line breaks) :/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting each of these elements in a separate div, giving them a fixed width, then floating them accordingly (be sure to clear your floats if you do this).

ie

```
<div id="leftImg" style="width:220px; float:left;">
<img src="..." />
</div>

<div id="slideShow" style="width:220px; float:left;">
<script>your script here</script>
</div>

<div id="rightImg" style="width:220px; float:left;">
<img src="..." />
</div>

<div style="clear:left;"></div>
```

Edit: There is nothing wrong with a slideshow script being in the body of your page. If it were a script that posted information then server side validation would have to be done for security purposes, but there is nothing wrong with how you're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Place the script inside a hidden div.

```
<div style="display:none"><script>...</script></div>
```